# Cannot Set Getters and Setters in Swift

Tags: swift

I have created a custom class and I want to add associated getters and setters. I have read the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1) from Apple and notice that when setting a getter and setter, you actually create a separate variable, which seems really confusing. For instance, in the documentation linked above, getters and setters are applied to a new variable called perimeter to obtain values from another variable called sidelength. Below is my code:

[image]

Comment: Given your attempted implementation of the setter and getter, there is no point in them. Just use `var key: String?` and that's it.

Comment: What do you mean? I want to essentially set a key value, and then get it later on so that I can pass it to a new ViewController

Comment: I know. That's what `var key: String?` does. You don't need to implement your own setter and getter. They are automatically created for every property. Only use your own setter and/or getter to make it a computed property. You should read that chapter in the Swift book.

Answer (score 1):

Getters and setters like you are implementing them are only used for computed variables in Swift. A variable with a getter and setter doesn't actually store anything, but does something when assigned or used for its value with other variables. When appropriate to use, the usage would be more like this.

```
var _key: String?

var key: String? {
    get {
        return _key
    }
    set {
        _key = newValue
    }
}
```

You would rarely if ever use this on an identical data type though. I use these for communication with CoreData often, and setting things like dates as a string or back to a date. Occasionally I might use it to handle the change in an optional to a non optional.

Getters and setters are not needed in order to use the variable in Swift though. If you are used to languages with them, I can understand the confusion here, but forget the correlation and start over with how you think about it. I am sure after a short amount of time, you will like the way Swift works with its datatypes!

Edit:

In order to do what you want, all you need is this:

```
class PollCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var key: String?
}
```

Now you can assign any value you want to `cell.key` and retrieve any value you want from `cell.key`.

Comment: This answer would be clearer (especially to a Swift newbie) by starting out showing that you don't even need the custom setter and getter in this case.

Comment: I agree, but if he actually reads what I wrote without just copying and pasting my response immediately, he should understand.

Comment: Perhaps but you should lead with the best solution and follow that up with additional information.

Comment: Thanks, so ultimately if I want to set a value for cell.key and then later obtain that value without a getter and setter, how would I do so?